# Is the clone repository created by `git clone` without `--bare` a repository with a working directory?

Tags: git

In Version Control with Git by Loeliger, it uses the following command to make a clone repository a bare repository i.e. a repository without a working directory

```
git clone --bare ~/public_html public_html.git
```

Is the clone repository created by `git clone` without `--bare` a repository with a working directory?

How can I tell if an existing repository has a working directory or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Simplest way to tell if a git repo is working or bare is to look for the existence of a .git directory inside the repo directory. If it has one, it is not a bare repo - and you will also see the files and directories that you keep in your repo. If the repo is bare, you will not see a .git directory because the repo directory only contains what would have been the contents of a .git directory.

Answer (score 2):

If the directory, after cloning, looks like the project you expect, then it's a working directory. It contains all the git information in the `.git` subdirectory.

If the directory, after cloning, looks nothing like the project you expect, and instead contains directories like `logs`, `objects`, `refs` and `hooks`, then it's a bare clone and has no working directory. Everything in there is used only by git. You can't work in that directory without damaging the repository. You would need to (non-`--bare`) clone this repo in order to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830712/4311135)

```
git rev-parse --is-bare-repository
```